# UILabel does not show full text after its height constraint is modified in code in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

[image illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Refie.jpg)
I have a UITableViewCell. In the content view of this cell, from top to bottom, I have an avatar UIImageView(1), a UILabel(2), a button to fold/unfold the UILabel(3), a UICollectionView(4), a UIStackView(5), and a UIView pretending to be the margin between table cells(6).

The top constraint of each object is connected to the bottom constraint of the object above. Except the UILabel(2), all the other objects have a certain height. For the label, I gave it a constraint that its height is less than or equal to 96(height with 5 lines).

After I tapped the button(3), I deactivated the height constraint of the label and tried to update the frame, hoping the label will take as much height as it needed to show all the text.

```
@IBAction func foldButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isFoldContent {
            checkinContentLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = false
            sender.setTitle("收起", for: .normal)
        } else {
            checkinContentLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = true
            sender.setTitle("展开", for: .normal)
        }

        isFoldContent = !isFoldContent

        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Unfortunately, after I tap the button, although both the boolean value of the `constraint.isActive` and the label height value are changed to the correct value, the label area does not spread out, meaning still not showing the folded text.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5SkQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

two things you need to do for this to work:
1. use “UITableViewAutomaticDimensions“
2. make sure your cell xib has defined vertical constraints from top to bottom.

Comment: I did those which did not help.